# QUERY_STRING only displays first parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I can only access my 1st URL parameter. I think it is because I have ampersands both in my RewriteRule as well as my QUERY_STRING. How can I access each parameter correctly in my PHP script?

I am making a request to

```
http://example.com/subdir/api/transport/1/car?type=fast&color=blue"
```

In my .htaccess file I have the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&params=%{QUERY_STRING}&api=$1 [L]
```

In my PHP, displaying `json_encode($_GET)` produces:

```
 {"q":"\/subdir\/api\/transport\/1\/car","params":"type=fast","color":"blue","api":"transport\/1\/car"}
```

You will notice that the "color":"blue" no longer has an equal sign and is not contained within "params".

If I therefore display `json_enocde($_GET['params']) all I get is the following:

```
"type=fast"
```

What can I do to acquire the full set of parameters? Is it an issue with my .htaccess or my PHP file?

Comment: Your rule should change to: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&api=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, this helped a lot. At first I got stuck with having a space after the comma, but without the space it works perfectly. Would you like to post an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` in target by using `QSA` flag that appends existing query string to target if you're modifying query parameters.

You can just use your rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&api=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think about the transformation that takes place:

```
index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&params=%{QUERY_STRING}&api=$1
```

becomes:

```
index.php?q=/subdir/api/transport/1/car&params=type=fast&color=blue&api=transport/1/car"
```

So, of *course* you are getting that for your `$_GET`.

What I would do is change the rewrite to:

```
index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING}&api=$1
```

And then in your code you will get:

```
{
    "q":"\/subdir\/api\/transport\/1\/car",
    "type": "fast",
    "color":"blue",
    "api":"transport\/1\/car"
}
```

If you want the params, you can then just remove the `q` and `api` keys from your `$_GET`.